# Joining two tables with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables :

[image]

This a part of my query to join two tables (tbl_ads and tbl_inf_adstate):

```
       @state_id int=NULL
    AS  
    BEGIN  
          SET NOCOUNT ON;  

SELECT a.Id
      ,a.ad_title
      ,a.ad_brief  
      ,a.ad_pic    
    INTO #Results  
    FROM [tbl_ads] a JOIN tbl_inf_adstate b ON a.Id=b.ad_id 
    WHERE (b.state_id=@state_id OR @state_id IS NULL) 
    AND a.ad_is_accept=1 
    AND a.ad_is_show=1 
    AND a.ad_is_slide=0 
    order by a.ad_type ASC,NEWID()
```

The `@state_id` parameter is optional.
My problem is that the result have multiple and repetitive records of an ad , but I want only 1 record of each ad .

This is the result :
[image]

Comment: @AaronBertrand for example **Golden 2** is repeated two times. But I want only one of that ad.

Comment: IMHO you've accepted the wrong answer. The ORDER BY in that answer does nothing but waste CPU and the code is a lot more complex than it has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this one :

SELECT  Id
      ,ad_title
      ,ad_brief  
      ,ad_pic    
INTO #Results
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.ID) AS rn, a.Id
      ,a.ad_title
      ,a.ad_brief  
      ,a.ad_pic
      ,a.ad_type    
    FROM [tbl_ads] a JOIN tbl_inf_adstate b ON a.Id=b.ad_id 
    WHERE (b.state_id=@state_id OR @state_id IS NULL) 
    AND a.ad_is_accept=1 
    AND a.ad_is_show=1 
    AND a.ad_is_slide=0 
)x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ad_type ASC,NEWID()
```

Comment: This is way more complicated than it has to be, and the ORDER BY is meaningless anyway.

Comment: the order by is not only meaningless but a waste

Comment: @Anil I want to get records randomized, when I use `select into #results` the ORDER BY is meaningless, but when I remove `INTO #Results` the select query is OK.

Comment: @Mike One more time - put your `ORDER BY NEWID()` on your eventual select ***FROM*** the #temp table, not the initial select ***INTO*** it.

Comment: @Mike If you are bound to randomize the records while inserting into #Temp table then 

use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn

Comment: @Anil the OP is inserting all the rows that meet the where clause. Why on earth would they be bound to randomize while inserting?

Answer (score 2):

Just distinguish them with `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Id
      ,a.ad_title
      ,a.ad_brief  
      ,a.ad_pic    
    INTO #Results  
    FROM [tbl_ads] a JOIN tbl_inf_adstate b ON a.Id=b.ad_id 
    WHERE (b.state_id=@state_id OR @state_id IS NULL) 
    AND a.ad_is_accept=1 
    AND a.ad_is_show=1 
    AND a.ad_is_slide=0
```

I have removed ordering because it makes no sense here. You should order your data when selecting from temp table not when inserting into that table.

Comment: Error: _ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified._

Comment: What does it mean `doesn't work`? You need to order by when you select from #Results. Ordering is guaranteed only when you add order by clause in your statement

Comment: @AaronBertrand, right, that's why I have asked the purpose of ordering by newid() when inserting in temp table

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri This statement is effectless : `order by a.ad_type ASC,NEWID()`

Comment: @Mike What do you mean by "effectless"? Are you later selecting from the #temp table without an ORDER BY? A table is an unordered bag of rows, and adding ORDER BY to an INSERT statement is no guarantee that subsequent queries without ORDER BY will return in any given order. If you want a specific ordering when selecting from the #temp table, ***add an ORDER BY then***. See #3 here: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT id, ad_title, ad_brief, ad_pic
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, adTitle, adBrief, ad_pic
```

Comment: No need for aggregations here, you can remove MAX-es

Answer (score 0):

remove the order by, its useless and a waste, add it to select

```
SELECT a.Id
      ,a.ad_title
      ,a.ad_brief  
      ,a.ad_pic    
    INTO #Results  
    FROM [tbl_ads] a
    WHERE @state_id IS NULL
    OR exists ( SELECT 1 FROM tbl_inf_adstate b 
                WHERE a.Id=b.ad_id AND b.state_id=@state_id) 
    AND a.ad_is_accept=1 
    AND a.ad_is_show=1 
    AND a.ad_is_slide=0
```

use an exists instead of a join and you'll have no duplicates and add a primary key to `tbl_inf_adstate` on both columns since you have at least 2 identical rows